Azure API Management OData Service not showing up in Developer Portal
I've imported an OData Service as an API in Azure API Management by following the steps in this official article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-api-from-odata
I expected the OData to show up in de APIM Developer Portal, but it isn't listed in de Api's page. I have all the permissions i need, and the OData Service API is also added to a product. The strange things is that when i navigate to the Products page, and select the product, the OData API is listed as an API of that product. But when i navigate to the API from here, it goes to the API page, but it says "The specified API does not exist".
Does the Developer Portal also support OData services, and if so, how do i get them to show up in the portal?

Have you published it after making the changes

@IkhtesamAfrin Yes, i've published the Developer Portal multiple times, if that's what you mean. Have you ever seen an OData service appearing in the Developer Portal?

I have the same issues with no odata APIs in the developer portal. I have created an issue on their github https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/2502

@HenningPedersen, i have made a support request in Azure Portal, and Microsoft support is investigating at the moment. I'll let you know when i have a answer, amd hopefully also a solution...

@HenningPedersen, Microsoft confirmed in an answer to my support call that there's no implementation for testing OData service from within the Developer Portal. The requirement is already on their backlog, but there's is no ETA at this moment. They will fix the issue that the API appearing on the Product's page as soon as possible, but  I guess we have to be more patient for OData support in the Developer Portal...


The strange things is that when i navigate to the Products page, and select the product, the OData API is listed as an API of that product. But when i navigate to the API from here, it goes to the API page, but it says "The specified API does not exist".


I believe adding OData API to a Product is also not yet supported. I have imported an OData API as shown below.


When I am navigating to a certain product to add this API, I am not getting this API in the list. Hence it is not supported yet.

You might be able to add it using the settings option.


I am also unable to see the imported OData API in developer Portal's API list page. After adding the API using settings option, I can see it under that product but it also shows The specified API doesn't exist message for me.
OData API type in Azure API Management is currently in Public Preview. So, I believe OData API's are not currently supported for Developer portal. I would suggest you to raise a feature request with the product team.

